# No Activity found to handle Intent com.android.phone.videocall

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to start a video call and I receive this error every time

```
E/AndroidRuntime(668): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.phone.videocall dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx (has extras) }
E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
```

Here is my code:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall");
callIntent.putExtra("videocall", true);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + prefs.getString("videonumber", "")));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

In my manifest I have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>` permission. I thought thats all you need but maybe I am wrong. My `videonumber` is in this format 1-xxx-xxx-xxxx. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any installed app that can handle this intent action on your device?

Comment: this is the simulator right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you do not have any applications installed on your phone, which could handle a video call.

That why is always good when calling external activities, to wrap all the code in a `try()catch{}` block, as you can't rely on the fact the user will have a such kink of app installed.

Comment: Isn't there a basic video call app on Android phones? Like iPhone has Facetime

Comment: I don't think there is any "default" app for video calls

Answer (score 0):

While `try-catch` will work, I would suggest using existing Android tools to check if an implicit `Intent` can be handled:

```
if (callIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Send the intent, it's safe
} else{
    // There is nothing that can handle this Intent
}
```